# How do I use an IF type structure in an UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

In T-SQL you can use a `CASE` statement when doing a `SELECT` to determine what sort of data you want to return. I'd like to do something like that, but not in a `SELECT` statement, but instead in an UPDATE statement. I don't know if this is the correct format or not, but hopefully you'll get the idea from this.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSomePS
    @Number1 int,
    @Number2 int,
    @Amt money
AS
BEGIN
    UPATE SomeTable
    CASE @Number1 +1 = @Number2
         MoneyColumn = MoneyColumn - @Amt
    ELSE
         MoneyColumn = MoneyColumn + @Amt
    END -- end the CASE statement
```

Will that so what I'm trying to do or is there another syntax?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - not a statement. It can return one atomic value based on some criteria

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression in `UPDATE` statement as in `SELECT` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSomePS
@Number1 int,
@Number2 int,
@Amt money
AS
BEGIN
UPATE SomeTable
SET MoneyColumn = 
  CASE WHEN @Number1 +1 = @Number2
       THEN MoneyColumn - @Amt
       ELSE MoneyColumn + @Amt
  END -- end the CASE statement
```

Comment: Really? I did not know that. I thought the CASE statement was only applicable to the SELECT statement. Well, cool, thanks Hamlet!